# Why phpMyAdmin shows "Loading" and doesn't respond well?

Tags: mysql

phpMyAdmin page shows "Loading" message and when I click to open my databases it doesn't respond.

How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Zeeshan Bro you need to check the following to make SQL run proper:

1. List item
2. No locking in the SQL query?
3. Open xampp and check whether the ports for apache are not changing as you are running SQL queries in mysql
4. Free some RAM
5. Clear previous mysql Sessions

**In Short** restart XAMPP or WAMPP or whatever server you are using. Free some memory